# XSLT concatenating two arrays

Tags: arrays, function, xslt

I'm trying to concatenate two string arrays in a special way. The arrays look like like this:

- first array (arg1): 'A', 'B', 'C'
- second array (arg2): '-3', '', '-4'

The result should be one string: 'A-3/B/C-4'

But with my code I'm getting a result like this (only the last part is returned): 'C-4'

Code:

```
<xsl:function name="functx:k" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="arg1" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:param name="arg2" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="indexedPath"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$arg1">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:variable name="indexedPathNew" select="concat($indexedPath, $arg1[$i], $arg2[$i], '/')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="indexedPath" select="$indexedPathNew"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$i=count($arg1)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$indexedPathNew"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>      
</xsl:function>
```

A second possibility would be to concatenate these two strings:

- first string: 'A/B/C'
- second string: '-3//-4'

The result again should be (one string): 'A-3/B/C-4'. I think that splitting and then concatenating is easier (I don't have any code for this, it is only an idea).

Can you please help me to find out what am I doing wrong, or how to do this properly?

Comment: When you repeat <xsl:variable name="indexedPath" select="$indexedPathNew"/>   you are creating a NEW variable each time, instead of reusing the "global variable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you simply want

```
<xsl:function name="functx:k" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="arg1" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:param name="arg2" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="string-join(for $pos in 1 to count($arg1)
return concat($arg1[$pos], $arg2[$pos]), '/')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Assuming XSLT/XPath 3.0 (as for instance already available with Saxon 9.6) you can simplify the code to

```
<xsl:function name="functx:k" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="arg1" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:param name="arg2" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="string-join(for-each-pair($arg1, $arg2, concat#2), '/')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Note that your arguments are sequences of strings, not arrays. You might get arrays as part of the language in version 3.1: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-arrays.